# Oracle converting date to number causes it to become 7 digits long instead of 8

Tags: oracle, date

I am currently converting a date to number using Oracle query. However for certain dates such as `08122019`, it is becoming as `8122019`

How can i tweak my query to show `0` in the beginning:

```
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(MyDate, 'DDMMYYYY'))
```

Comment: A number does not have a starting `0`. A string may have one. If you want a string, just do not use `TO_NUMBER()`.

Comment: It would be better to use the format `yyymmdd` and convert that to a number. That way the number also sorts correctly in terms of a date.

Comment: Why do you need dates converted into numbers in that format? It doesn't seem very useful. And anyway, numbers only have formats when they are displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is (though I have no idea why you would want the 3rd one, if what you're asking for is the first):

```
    SQL> select to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy')  from dual;

    TO_CHAR(
    --------
    08122019


    SQL> select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy')) from dual;

    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DDMMYYYY'))
    --------------------------------------
                                   8122019


    SQL> select to_char(to_number(to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy')),'09999999') from dual;

    TO_CHAR(T
    ---------
     08122019
```